# How to create rounded corners without the edges SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a rounded corner look without the edges, how is this possible in SwiftUI?[image]

Comment: Either draw the elements yourself in a Shape, or Canvas, or use `RoundedRectangle` and the clip out the parts you don't want visible

Comment: The text of this question combined with the sample image provides a decent description of what the OP is trying to do. I think we should re-open it. Sure, the phrasing of the question could be better, but let's ask edits instead of just closing it. We shouldn't be so harsh with new posters.

Comment: @DuncanC There is no code, no attempt to solve this from OP so it's more of a request than a proper question. Also, OP has been a member for over 5 years and asked a bunch of question already.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have some sympathy for "how in the world can I do x?" type questions. Sometimes you have no idea how to even start with a problem like this. I would likely build a Shape object containing a series of arcs. Benzy's answer is much, much simpler, and I would never have thought of it.

Comment: This strikes me as quite a unique problem that looks deceptively simple, yet it's not. I would be interested to see other ways of solving it because I might be able to learn something. The first comment suggests "clipping out the parts you don't want visible", but it is not clear to me how that can be done. Agreed, there was no attempt at an initial solution, but that's perhaps because it's not trivial. I suppose the OP could have shown how a RoundedRectangle is drawn over an Image, but that would hardly have given much lead. I find it a shame that other answers are now blocked: +1 to re-open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `RoundedRectangle` to provide the base shape, then the sides can be hidden using blocks of the same Color and blend mode `.destinationOut`. For the thin line that goes all the way round, just paint another `RoundedRectangle` on top.

This shape can be applied as an overlay over the image. It is important that `.compositingGroup()` or `.drawingGroup()` is then applied to the group, so that the blend mode doesn't take effect for the underlying image too.

```swift
Image(systemName: "lizard.fill")
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFit()
    .padding(6)
    .frame(width: 200, height: 250)
    .foregroundStyle(.orange)
    .background(.blue)
    .overlay {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(.white, lineWidth: 2)
                .padding()
            Color.white
                .padding(.vertical, 40)
                .blendMode(.destinationOut)
            Color.white
                .padding(.horizontal, 40)
                .blendMode(.destinationOut)
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(.white.opacity(0.2), lineWidth: 1)
                .padding()
        }
        .compositingGroup() // or .drawingGroup()
    }
```

[image: Screenshow]

Comment: Very cool. You make SwiftUI look easy. (Voted.) I'm still really struggling. (However, that's a funny-looking baby in your output! <grin>.)